# Booleans modifier glitching meshes

Tags: modifiers, eevee-render-engine, displacement

I'm trying to use booleans to make a fake stylized fire motion . I have two meshes, both are identical, one is just smaller than the other to achieve the stylizied fire effect I'm going for. Both of them have two displacement modifiers, using empties and circles to move the displacement texture. Settings are the same for both of them and under both displacement modifiers I added a boolean modifier to both, tried to the same object so I can create holes for the desired effect I'm aiming for:-

[image]

The problem is that at random intervals the boolean modifier makes the mesh glitch out for no reason, I've tried moving the boolean modifier on top of both displacement mods but that only causes it to glitch even further, I've [recorded it in motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zZ1Y-tnOcw) so maybe it can help understand the problem better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you could try the new boolean modifier from V2.91 ? The exact method is supposed to be way more reliable.

Comment: @2Fleur2 for the next time please insert images and files into your Q, not as external links that are not permanent and later can devaluate your Q for others. Instead video try image sequence or anim gif instead of video to show core of your issue. Blend file can be attached via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com servis. Thank you for help to keep this site meaningful.

Comment: Just a comment, but it looks like from the side it is glitching out when the center of the cylinder is in contact with the larger, darker mesh.  So center through smaller mesh and center outside both meshes are fine...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat If you mean origin - its just coincidence, you can test it by your self, if you go to Transform Options and enable Only Origins and move the origin you can see it is still corrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change slightly *Strenght* value of first Displace modifier.

Or move vertices a bit on Y axis.**

In this case t is caused by first Displace modifier that brings vertices in conflict position for boolean operation. Usually it is some overlapping geometry that creates weird cut that collaps all system :)

Sometimes helps to change *Overlap Threshold* value, but not in this case. In general just change a bit topology in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean modifier has its glitches, there are situations that are difficult to resolve by the current math behind it. Its also known by the developers, although a few attempts have been made to recode it, as far as i know it still has problems.

Its better i think to think of other faking method, be creative.